# Is there a way to put tag code into servlet code?

Tags: java, servlets, taglib

I have this custom tag that was created by my boss.

```
<lib:Menu user_id=\"<%=  user.getId()%>\" />\n
```

I'm currently in the process of trying to move the HTML code that existed in a jsp file into a servlet file. Problem is that I don't know how to make a call to the custom library tag to get the HTML that he had created.

Is there a way to call the tag to get the HTML out of it? Is there a way to get HTML out of a tag?

Comment: If anywhere, HTML belongs in the JSP and **not** in the servlet. Why do you want the HTML in your Java code?

Comment: You need to look at the tag definition. It would be in a .tld file in WEB-INF or a .tag file in WEB-INF/tags. If you provide details of the tag definition someone might be able to help further.. Essentially the tag invokes java code defined in a class file. You need to figure that out and invoke the code directly from your servlet..

Comment: It's because of the conditions that are based on the database. Too many conditions to keep it within a JSP page.